# Disable interrupts in windows

Tags: windows, driver, interrupt

I need to execute a piece of code atomically. I suppose the only way is to disable the interrupts, how can I do that under windows? I'm searching a windows OS which allows me to do that, so I'm no focusing on a particular windows. Even Windows CE would be good.

Stefano

Comment: On desktop and above versions of windows you may not disable interrupts from the user-space application. If you really think you need to - then you should reconsider the design. As for CE & Mobile - I have no information, but I suspect that there is the same situation. What kind of driver you are developing?

Comment: I don't need to stay in the user-space, it is possible to disable the interrupts creating something at kernel level? Maybe a software driver?

Comment: Could you please be more precise. What resource you are going to protect from concurrent access with such a hammer :)?

Comment: I have to execute periodically a RAM test on a system embedded. This test must be atomic.

Comment: Not really, it's a classic RAM test (write and read, write 0x55 and 0xaa...). The reason they want me to do it atomic it's not my point. Under Linux I've addressed the problem adding a new system call or adding a kernel module, but I really don't knwo how to move under windows.

Comment: look at this article please: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551779(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Disabling interrupts for long periods of time will likely lead to system instability, even if you manage it. Certain things don't like being ignored.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487402.aspx

Comment: Since Windows is not designed to allow this, your best bet might be to write a hypervisor, or (more realistically) to modify an open-source hypervisor such as Xen.  Keep in mind that if the hardware might have multiple cores you'll have to cope with that somehow.  There are also other possible complications such as Systems Management Interrupts (SMI) depending on the hardware platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of user-written code completely disabling interrupts pretty much goes against some fundamental design assumptions of Windows.

For starters, you can't disable interrupts from a user-mode application.  (It is a privileged instruction.)

In kernel mode, you can use IRQL to prevent most premption (but not all).  This is the "standard" way to perform non-preemptible hardware operations under Windows.  I suspect this is what you are really looking for.  If you can get your code to run within the confines of a higher-level IRQL, you should be ok.  [See this link for info on IRQL.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/IRQL_thread.doc&ei=H9BlUMWJHeP00gGY2YDYDw&usg=AFQjCNGN8B8iueodNRqGgsn61r6mbr8gPg&sig2=y-WLPB485cN4dA9kA2NxQg)
Keep in mind that this higher you run, the more things are going to break.  Expect Performance Counters to become inaccurate, device buffers to overflow, etc.

As a back door, you could embed raw assembly CLI/STI instructions into a kernel driver, but this will probably break lots of things, unless your code disables interrupts for a very brief period of time.  If not, expect a blue screen.  Additionally, I believe the AMD64 compiler will fight against you trying to do inline Assembly.

I highly reccomend that you back off from your atomicity requirement.

**Some other options:**

- Boot to your own environment to run your tests (similar to Memtest86).
- Consider using a parent RTOS kernel.  There are off the-shelf "Windows RTOS" solutions that run Windows as a subprocess of a parent RTOS.  Existing Windows applications and drivers run fine, and time-critical/atomic tasks are written for the RTOS.  The most popular player in the space is [RTX from IntervalZero](http://www.intervalzero.com/).

**Also, there is a dirty little secret about x86 you should know:**  Almost nothing you write on an x86 platform is guaranteed to be atomic, even if you write your RTOS in assembly.  There are System Management Interrupts that can interrupt your code, even if you do a CLI/STI.

Comment: For MSVC, there are `_disable` and `_enable` intrinsics available in `dos.h` (or you can manually declare them and mark as such with `#pragma intrinsic(<name>)`) which corresponds to `CLI` and `STI`. If for any reason you have to save and restore `EFLAGS` (which IMHO should be preferred over plain `STI`), you have `__readeflags` and `__writeeflags`.